# NoMethodError in Stocks#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create a stock market app and I have a button that is breaking my web app. My issue is with this bit of embedded ruby on my

show.html.erb page:

```
<%= render @stock %>
<div>
  <%= link_to "Edit this stock", edit_stock_path(@stock) %> |
  <%= link_to "Back to stocks", stocks_path %>
  <%= button_to "Delete this stock", @stock, method: :delete %>
</div>
```

This`@stock.destroy` line is needed for removing entries for a user. The error rails throws:

```
Showing C:/stockmarketapp/app/views/stocks/show.html.erb where line #9 raised:

undefined method `destroy' for #<StockQuote::Stock:0x000001f7fc0aa780 @attribution="Data provided for free by IEX (https://iexcloud.io).",
@response_code=200, @avg_total_volume=2261555,
@calculation_price="close", @change=-0.36, @change_percent=-0.00331,
@close=108.41, @close_source="official", @close_time=1654286400058,
@company_name="BlackRock Institutional Trust Company N.A. - iShares Core High Dividend ETF", @currency="USD", @delayed_price=108.4,
@delayed_price_time=1654286390674, @extended_change=0, @extended_change_percent=0, @extended_price=108.41,
@extended_price_time=1654300800004, @high=108.93, @high_source="15
minute delayed price", @high_time=1654286395170, @iex_ask_price=nil,
@iex_ask_size=nil, @iex_bid_price=nil, @iex_bid_size=nil,
@iex_close=108.43, @iex_close_time=1654286330444,
@iex_last_updated=nil, @iex_market_percent=nil, @iex_open=108.81,
@iex_open_time=1654263316934, @iex_realtime_price=nil,
@iex_realtime_size=nil, @iex_volume=nil,
@last_trade_time=1654286394157, @latest_price=108.41,
@latest_source="Close", @latest_time="June 3, 2022",
@latest_update=1654286400058, @latest_volume=876363, @low=108.25,
@low_source="15 minute delayed price", @low_time=1654273215082,
@market_cap=13133871500, @odd_lot_delayed_price=108.395,
@odd_lot_delayed_price_time=1654286390033, @open=108.33,
@open_time=1654263000128, @open_source="official", @pe_ratio=nil,
@previous_close=108.77, @previous_volume=1062893,
@primary_exchange="NYSE ARCA", @symbol="HDV", @volume=876363,
@week52_high=110.91, @week52_low=91.09,
@ytd_change=0.07801100501710605, @is_us_market_open=false>
Extracted source (around line #9):78910
              
  <%= link_to "Edit this stock", edit_stock_path(@stock) %> |
  <%= link_to "Back to stocks", stocks_path %>
  <%= button_to "Delete this stock", @stock.destroy, method: :delete %>
</div>

Rails.root: C:/stockmarketapp

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/stocks/show.html.erb:9
```

These are my files related to `@stock` and `@stock.destroy`:

```
class StocksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_stock, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  @api = StockQuote::Stock.new(api_key: "pk_153e93f4bce64c3d87e7d4d3510153ed")


  # GET /stocks or /stocks.json
  def index
    @stocks = Stock.all
  end

  # GET /stocks/1 or /stocks/1.json
  def show
    @stocks = Stock.all
  end

  # GET /stocks/new
  def new
    @stock = Stock.new
  end

  # GET /stocks/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /stocks or /stocks.json
  def create
    @stock = Stock.new(stock_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @stock.save
        format.html { redirect_to stock_url(@stock), notice: "Stock was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @stock }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @stock.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /stocks/1 or /stocks/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @stock.update(stock_params)
        format.html { redirect_to stock_url(@stock), notice: "Stock was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @stock }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @stock.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /stocks/1 or /stocks/1.json
  def destroy
    @stock.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to stocks_url, notice: "Stock was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def correct_user
    @ticker = current_user.stocks.find_by(id: params[:id])
    redirect_to stocks_path, notice: "Not Autherized to edit this stock" if @ticker.nil?
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_stock
      @stock = Stock.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def stock_params
      params.require(:stock).permit(:ticker, :user_id)
    end
end
```

Stock partial:

```
  <% @stock= StockQuote::Stock.quote(stock.ticker) %>

  <div id="<%= dom_id stock %>">
    <p>
      <strong>Ticker:</strong>
      <%= @stock.symbol %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <strong>Open</strong>
     $<%= @stock.open %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <strong>Price</strong>
     $<%= @stock.latest_price %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <strong>Close</strong>
     $<%= @stock.close %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <strong>Company Name</strong>
      <%= @stock.company_name %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <strong>Primary Exchange</strong>
      <%= @stock.primary_exchange %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <strong>Volume</strong>
      <%= number_with_delimiter(@stock.volume, :delimiter => ',') %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <strong>Market Cap</strong>
      $<%= number_with_delimiter(@stock.market_cap, :delimiter => ',') %>
    </p>
    

  </div>
```

Github Repo: https://github.com/Maikkeru/Stockmarketapp

I assume that am wielding the stock object incorrectly but I don't know where that slipup is occurring. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code and the error as text and not as images.

Comment: The button should be `<%= button_to "Delete this stock", @stock, method: :delete %>` not `@stock.destroy` which would actually delete the stock when you're rendering the view! Also that doesn't appear to be an ActiveRecord model that can be destroyed.